# Is a function multiplying a constant matrix continuous?

Tags: functions, continuity

Suppose that we have a function $f: \mathbb{R}^K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^J$.

Specifically, the function $f$ just products a $(J\times K)$ constant matrix, say $c$, to the argument.

For example, let $K=2$, $J=3$, and $c=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\\
3 & 4\\
5 & 6
\end{pmatrix}$.

Then, $f\left[\begin{pmatrix}
7 \\
7
\end{pmatrix}\right]=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\\
3 & 4\\
5 & 6
\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
7 \\
7
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
7+14 \\
21+28 \\
35+42
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
21 \\
49 \\
77
\end{pmatrix}$.

**That is, $f(x)=c\cdot x$.**

Here, I am wondering whether this kind of function multiplying a constant matrix is a continuous function.

Comment: [This](https://math.colorado.edu/~nita/Continuity2.pdf) might be good resource.

Comment: Yes, it is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use every polynomial function is continuous, and multivariable function $f=\sum f_ie_i$ is continuous if and only if every coordinate function $f_i$ is continuous.

I'll let $i$-th row of $A$ as $A^i$, then $f:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^n, f(X)=AX$ must be:

$$f(X)=\begin{pmatrix}A^1\\A^2\\\vdots\\A^n\end{pmatrix}X=\begin{pmatrix}A^1\cdot X\\A^2\cdot X\\\vdots \\A^n\cdot X\end{pmatrix}.$$

For all $i\ (1\le i\le n)$, coordinate function $f_i(X)=A^i\cdot X=\sum_j A_{ij}X_j$ is polynomial, so continuous.

Therefore, $f$ is also continuous.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution :)